# Google App Engine authentication with password

Tags: google-app-engine

I am really fed up. All I see the Google App Engine tutorial was just making the example on how to authenticate without password. What if I want to authenticate directly from my gmail account, how can I do it???

Answer (score 1):

User the google provided **users** service which can use your google account for auth.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers

> Google App Engine provides several useful services based on Google infrastructure, accessible by applications using libraries included with the SDK. One such service is the Users service, which lets your application integrate with Google user accounts. With the Users service, your users can use the Google accounts they already have to sign in to your application.